# How to determine what value has changed on scene update

Tags: python, scene, depsgraph

I'm considering writing a Take Manager addon so that Blender can have the same functionality as Houdini's Take system (where you can create multiple "takes" that inherit properties from the main scene, but certain values can be unlocked and changed, such as subdivision surface levels, physics substeps, or whatever else).

I've written code for watchers of specific values, but is there an efficient way to know which of all the properties was changed each time the scene updates?

Thanks!